# Magento2 multistore setup

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am trying to set up a multi-store in Magento 2 using localhost, followed this two tutorials but not working. Can anyone please explain step by step?

1. [Tutorial 1](http://blog.belvg.com/multistore-in-magento-2-0.html)
2. [Tutorial 2](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Follow Link to setup multi-store:

https://magecomp.com/blog/setup-multi-store-in-magento-2/